# VueJs 3 composition api usage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I created a component in VueJs using the composition api.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value"  placeholder="hello">
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineProps} from "vue";
interface SearchProps {
  onChange: () => void;
  name: string;
  created: string;
}
let value = ref('')
const props = defineProps<SearchProps>()
setup() {

}
///TS2304: Cannot find name 'setup'.

</script>

<style scoped>
input {
  width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

My component gets 3 props: `onChange, name, created`. I want to type my props using typescript, for this i used: `const props = defineProps<SearchProps>()`, also i need to interact with passed props, but using the scenario above `props` is `null`, and also i can not use `setup` method to be able to write the code logic. 
 Question: Why i got these issues, and how using my example to be able to type the props using typescript, and to be able to create code logic?

Comment: `and also i can not use setup method to be able to write the code logic.` change `<script lang="ts">` to `<script setup lang="ts">`

Comment: @bassxzero If i add this i get `TS2304: Cannot find name 'setup'.`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of vue3?

Comment: Passing a function as Prop is considered bad practice. We use events instead.

Comment: @bassxzero, so my question is using composition api i need to use `setup` function or not according the last VueJs version?

Comment: the `setup()` is not required if you put `setup` in the script attribute.

Comment: I believe the latest version of vue suggests using the `<script setup lang="ts">` syntactic sugar instead of using the `setup()` function

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html <- check this out, if you want `<script setup lang="ts">`

Comment: and if you want `setup(){}`, this is the way to go -> https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage

Comment: and don't pass `onChange` as prop, if you want your child to communicate with parent, there's something called `defineEmits`. refer here -> https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

Comment: @MinSomai, also why i can not read `value` in console.log when user type something within the input, but i need to wrap it in `watchEffect`?

Comment: @bassxzero, also why i can not read value in console.log when user type something within the input, but i need to wrap it in watchEffect?

Comment: You'll need to log `value.value`. That's just how `ref` in vue works. -> https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref